# Rails interpolate action_name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code structure:

```
<% types = [
    {
        one: 'one 1',
        two: 'two 2',
        three: 'three 3'
    }
] %>
<% result = types[:#{action_name}]%>

<% puts result %>
```

The `one`, `two` and `three` are actions I have, which I want to interpolate in the `result` variable, so the result of an action would get the according object in the `types` array. How can I do this, what I did seems to return an error.

`:#{action_name}` it returns an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is wrong syntactically.

Fix is : `:"#{action_name}"` . And you don't need a Array of hash, only hash is enough.

```
<% types =
    {
        one: 'one 1',
        two: 'two 2',
        three: 'three 3'
    }
%>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. BTW, what is the difference between the array syntax `[ ]` and the one you used `{ }`?

Comment: @GEspinha One is Array literal and `{}` is a Hash literal.

Comment: What is the difference between them?

Comment: [array](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html) and [hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you have array of hash then you can access first array element:

```
types.first[:"#{action_name}"]
```

Or you can use loop for accessing hash.

If you need only hash then you should follow @Arup Rakshit answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of things wrong with your solution.

1) `types = [{ one: "one1", ... }]` is not a hash, it is an **array** with a hash in it. It looks like you want a hash, so it should be written as `types = { one: "one1", ... }`

2) You want to access an element from the hash by effectively doing `types[:one]`. To interpolate a variable into a symbol you need to do use the quotes, i.e. `:"#{var}"`. So the assignment line should be `result = types[:"#{action_name}"]`

3) It seems you are doing this in a template, which is a strange place to variable assignment of any sort. I suggest you move all this code into a controller (for a start, at least).

---